# Displaying Axis Percentages in ggplot2 without: `scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)`

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, drc

I would like to display percents on the Y-Axis. It appears the most common method of doing this is in ggplot2 is via scales: `scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)`.

I am **unable to use this method** because I am implementing `labels=every_nth`, a custom function to display minor tick marks on the Y axis

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(all_mydata, aes(x=dose,y=probability, group=model))+
geom_point(aes(col=model, shape=model))+


#X-Axis transformation:  
  annotation_logticks(scaled = TRUE,sides="b") +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = 10^(-1:10),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+



  #Y axis minor ticks using "every_nth", for minor ticks.
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1,0.05), 
                     labels=every_nth(seq(0,1,0.05),2,inverse=TRUE))

 # scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) #conflicts with previous scale_y_continuous call
```

[image]

data - not extremely relevant to this case

```
all_mydata<-structure(list(dose = c(3, 3, 25, 25, 25, 50, 50, 50), total = c(25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), affected = c(1L, 3L, 22L, 
14L, 22L, 23L, 16L, 21L), probability = c(0.04, 0.12, 0.88, 0.56, 
0.88, 0.92, 0.64, 0.84), model = c("mod1", "mod1", "mod1", "mod1", 
"mod1", "mod1", "mod1", "mod1")), .Names = c("dose", "total", 
"affected", "probability", "model"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 51L, 
52L, 53L, 73L, 74L, 75L), class = "data.frame")
```

Custom Function, found on stack exchange which draws minor tick marks on Y axis

```
every_nth <- function(x, nth, empty = TRUE, inverse = FALSE) 
{
  if (!inverse) {
    if(empty) {
      x[1:nth == 1] <- ""
      x
    } else {
      x[1:nth != 1]
    }
  } else {
    if(empty) {
      x[1:nth != 1] <- ""
      x
    } else {
      x[1:nth == 1]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can change your `every_nth` function to something like that:

```
every_nth <- function(x, nth, empty = TRUE, inverse = FALSE) 
{
    if (!inverse) {
        if(empty) {
            x[1:nth == 1] <- ""
            out <- x
        } else {
            out <- x[1:nth == 1]
        }
    } else {
        if(empty) {
            x[1:nth != 1] <- ""
            out <- x

        } else {
            out <- x[1:nth == 1]
        }
    }
    out2 <- paste0(100*as.numeric(out), "%")
    out2[out2 == "NA%"] <- ""
    out2
}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought to modify the function like that!  Works perfectly, thank you!